# Xamarin.Forms HttpClient.GetAsync Blocks UI Thread

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await

Using `await client.GetAsync(uri)` blocks my UI thread.

Here's the code inside my button click event handler:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = new MainPageViewModel();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;

        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:50715/api/values"));

        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri); // This is where UI gets blocked
        SongView.ItemsSource = new List<Song>();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            vm.Songs = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Song>>(content);
            });
        }

        SongView.ItemsSource = vm.Songs;
    }
```

And even with just this code it still blocks the UI on the same line.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;

        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:50715/api/values"));

        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri); // This is where UI gets blocked
    }
```

Can you point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is that really just the code? You're getting a response from the server and doing nothing with it?

Comment: @Kharlan Can you post a reproducible example of the issue? The code provided does not block the UI thread. In your second sample how are you determining the UI thread is blocked, are you using an activity indicator? What is the purpose of setting the `MaxResponseContentBufferSize` in your code, especially in the second sample? Can you be more specific about the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: @JSteward I'm debugging on a UWP app running in Local Machine. When I click the button that calls this event handler, I an't move the window while it's loading.

Comment: @Paulo Morgado I'm using it to populate a list into a ListView. In my second example i'm just pointing out that the line that calls `await client.GetAsync(uri)` is blocking the UI

Comment: @JSteward You're right. My code does not block the UI. I tried debugging it on an android emulator. Probably the freeze that I see is being caused by visual studio while debugging a UWP app on Local Machine.

Comment: I have the same problem in a WPF app. The `.GetAsync` method does block the UI thread. It might be because it returns a long string.